# Where can I see the list of selected files for a commit in GitHub for Windows?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Where can I see the list of selected files for a commit in GitHub for Windows?

By default  GitHub for Windows lists both selected and unselected files:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.